# How to control the scope of Dependency Injection in .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

We are developing a class library in .Net 2.0 Core. We use dependency injection straight out of the box. We have some services that we want to resolve from the container as "Scoped".

How can we start (and end) such Scope in code. It would be nice to be able to do this during some of our more elaborate test scenarios.

Note: we do not use "ASP.Net Core"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; // it's an extension method



using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
   // in your new Scope, use the scope's ServiceProvider
   var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SomeService>();

}
```